Conflicting JVM specs between what can be verified run and what is debuggable wrt local variables?
On one hand the Java class spec says:

There may be no more than one LocalVariableTable attribute per local variable in the attributes table of a Code attribute.

But on the other hand lots of research papers ponder the problem that at JVM bytecode verification (and execution) level you can have conflicting types for a local variable in different regions of a method. E.g. Leroy (2003)

The least upper bound of two types for a register (or stack slot) can be 'top', causing this register
to have type
'top' in the merged state. This corresponds to the situation where a register holds values
of incompatible types in two arms of a conditional (e.g. int in one arm and an object reference in
the other), and therefore is treated as uninitialized (no further loads from this register) after the
merge point.

So, does that mean the JVM spec for the debugging info is partly broken, in that it cannot represent debugging info in such [complex] cases, where the local variable is reused with a different type in the same method? (Those would need multiple records in the LocalVariableTable, one for each range that has a different type. But the spec seem to forbid that.)
Of course, the verification algorithm has changed substantially (from type inference described in that [2003] paper) to type checking using StackMapTables for class version >= 50. Does the latter prohibit the situation from the 2nd quote?  (And if so, is the spec conflict between what's verifiable and what's debuggable [local-variables wise] limited to class version <= 49?)

N.B. It's easy [at least for me!] to sometimes confuse the requirements for the stack with those for the local variables. While on merging even JDK 1.0 required the stack to have identical types (except for refs), that's not the case with local variables. From the very first JMV spec (1996):

To merge two local variable states, corresponding pairs of local variables are
compared. If the two types are not identical, then unless both contain reference
values, the verifier records that the local variable contains an unusable value. If both
of the pair of local variables contain reference values, the merged state contains a
reference to an instance of the first common superclass of the two types.

That sentence/para is nearly identical e.g. in JDK 11 spec:

To merge two local variable array states, corresponding pairs of local variables are compared. The value of the merged local variable is computed using the rules above, except that the corresponding values are permitted to be different primitive types. In that case, the verifier records that the merged local variable contains an unusable value.

However this doesn't cause verification to fail (unlike the similar situation with stacks) at least in the spec.
So, what Leroy wrote checks out against the JVM spec. Thus, since it's  valid bytecode to have different types for the same locals on branches, unless you later read from that local, my question remains valid: is that situation not representable in the LocalVariableTable, for debugging purposes?

The subject of the sentence is “LocalVariableTable attribute”, not “entry within the LocalVariableTable attribute”. The rather surprising information that more than one LocalVariableTable attribute is allowed at a Code attribute is already hinted in the preceding sentence:

If multiple LocalVariableTable attributes are present in the attributes table of a Code attribute, then they may appear in any order.

The specified limit of “at most one LocalVariableTable attribute per local variable” is of little relevance in practice, given that one LocalVariableTable attribute is sufficient to describe all local variables of a method. I’ve never seen multiple LocalVariableTable attributes at a method in real life and just verified that not even libraries like the widely used ASM library are prepared to handle multiple LocalVariableTable attributes at one method.
The HotSpot JVM, however, does accept multiple LocalVariableTable attributes at a Code attribute (I just checked this) and verifies that there are no duplicate entries throughout all of them. But “duplicate entry” means “entry with the same combination of start_pc, length, name, and index” here and just altering one of those value made the JVM accept it, despite being contradicting. On the other hand, it’s not clear why the JVM enforces a constraint not explicitly mentioned in the specification, in an optional debug attribute, in the first place.

So, for more clarity, the solution is to use multiple (LVT) tables, each with an entry for that (same) local variable, but with different (start+length) spans? (By the way, in the meantime, I checked that OpenJDK's JVM does run code where e.g. a ('primitive') byte[] ref is storead a local and then that same local is overwritten with a String ref. I actually found bytecode like this 'in the wild'.)

No, as said in the answer “one LocalVariableTable attribute is sufficient to describe all local variables of a method”. There is no reason to ever use multiple tables and, as also said in the answer, some bytecode processing libraries are not even prepared to handle multiple tables. The test I did, was only to check whether the JVM adheres to the literal interpretation of the spec (i.e. that multiple tables are supported, even when there’s no point in defining multiple tables).

Why is there no point if the spec forbids multiple entries in the same table for the same variable? Unless 'same variable' means the combination of name, start, and length. Which the spec isn't exactly clear that that's meant by 'same variable'...

I does nowhere forbid multiple entries for the same variable. As the first sentence of my answer says, the sentence you’ve cited does not even talk about entries of the table. Reusing a variable index is commonplace. Take for example, if(Math.random() > 0.5) { int i = 42; } else { String s = "foo"; } All compilers in the wild will use the same index for i and s. And store their information in one table. As said, I’ve never seen multiple tables in the wild.

TLDR nutshell: javac -g does indeed generate multiple row entries for the same slot in the LVT (with diff ranges and types) as long as those slots are read somewhere. If they're only written, it doesn't generate LVT entries for them, even if the store instructions appear in the bytecode. (I suppose it might be so because javac -g computes def-use chains and if some slot is not used after being assigned [on some branch], there's no def-use as such.)

I checked the example indicated in comments on the other answer and while slot reuse does indeed (easily) happen, the LVT generated by javac -g from JDK 1.8 has zero entries (!) for the slot, in that case. (I guess I should have not used the main method to test, since that adds its own layer of confusion, because the main args does get an LVT entry. But at least we know that LVT generation works...)
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Math.random:()D
         3: ldc2_w        #3                  // double 0.5d
         6: dcmpl
         7: ifle          16
        10: bipush        42
        12: istore_1
        13: goto          19
        16: ldc           #5                  // String foo
        18: astore_1
        19: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
        line 5: 19
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      20     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
        frame_type = 16 /* same */
        frame_type = 2 /* same */
}

So, unless there's a bug in javap and it can't display the LVT with two entries for the same LV slot (and shows none in that case), it seems that the official compiler cannot produce multiple LVT rows for the same var, when the slot is reused. Whether this is because they think only one row is allowed (as I did) or this is some other bug/issue in the toolchain, IDK...
Just to be sure, I've made the example more complicated to also use the variables, in case there's optimization throwing away the LVT entries for defined but never used variables. And... indeed that was the issue. I do get two rows for slot 1 now:
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Math.random:()D
         3: ldc2_w        #3                  // double 0.5d
         6: dcmpl
         7: ifle          23
        10: bipush        42
        12: istore_1
        13: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        16: iload_1
        17: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
        20: goto          33
        23: ldc           #7                  // String foo
        25: astore_1
        26: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        29: aload_1
        30: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        33: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
        line 5: 10
        line 6: 13
        line 7: 20
        line 9: 23
        line 10: 26
        line 12: 33
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           13       7     1     i   I
           26       7     1     s   Ljava/lang/String;
            0      34     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
        frame_type = 23 /* same */
        frame_type = 9 /* same */

So multiple LVT rows are allowed and generated by javac -g for the same slot, if there is use for the values written.
